# How forces act on the two masses on a rotating table

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Consider a system on the figure: two masses on a rotating turntable are connected by a string over a frictionless pulley.

[image]

The masses of the bodies are related as $m_A<m_B$. They are at distance $R$ from the center of the turntable.

The turntable is slowly accelerating, until it reaches some angular velocity $\omega_0$. After that the lower mass (B) slips outwards. The static friction coefficient between the blocks and the between the block and the table is $\mu$.

It is necessary to find $\omega_0$.

In order to do that, I'm writing the Newton's law for each body:

- Body A: $\quad m_A{\bf \ddot r} = m_A{\bf g}+{\bf N}_A + {\bf T}+{\bf F}_A$
- Body B: $\quad m_B{\bf \ddot r} = (m_A+m_B){\bf g}+{\bf N}_B + {\bf T}-{\bf F}_A+{\bf F}_B$

where ${\bf T}$ is for tension of the string acting on each body, ${\bf F}_{A}$ is friction between A and B, and ${\bf F}_B$ is friction between B and the turntable.

After that I shoul probably go to the cylindric coordinates $(r, \theta, z)$ and write the equations above component-by-component. However, I cannot understand what is the condition of B slipping outwards, and why is there a such a critical value $\omega_0$.

How do the forces of friction act in this case?

Please, help me to understand the physics behind this situation. Any kind of hint will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The condition of B slipping outward is a statement that the forces providing the centripetal acceleration (here friction) are too weak to keep block B from moving (as centripetal force depends on velocity since the magnitude is $m\omega^2$)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: John Rennie, thank you for your comment! I did not ask anyone to do my exercise. I was confused with the concept of how the friction forces act in this case, and why there should be such a critical value \omega_0. For instance, I was unable to comprehend what determines the direction of friction forces acting on each body. Now, having the answers of Bill Watts and Triatticus, I understand the direction is determined by the direction of motion of masses, and the critical angular velocity exists because the friction force cannot be infinite. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally easiest assign the pieces and add them when you have all the pieces defined.  I see $\mu$ is missing from your equations, so something is wrong.  When the blocks start slipping is when the friction force is $\mu\ N$.  Prior to that it is lower.

The friction force on block A:

$\text{FrA}=-\mu\  \text{mA}\ g$

I am calling to the right positive and to the left negative.  Block A slips to the right and its friction force is opposite, so it is negative.

The friction force on Block B is positive.

$\text{FrB}=\mu\  (\text{mA}+\text{mB}) g$

Now find $\text{$\Sigma $F}=m\ a$ for each block. The acceleration for each block is its respective $\frac{m\ v^2}{r}=m\ r\ \omega^2$

Block A

$T+FrA=mA\ R\ \omega 0^2$

and block B

$T+FrB-FrA=mB\ R\ \omega 0^2$

Plugging in for the $FrA$ and $FrB$ from above and solving the two equations for $T$ and $\omega 0$, we get

$T=\frac{2 g\ \mu\ mA\ (mA+mB)}{mB-mA}$

$\omega 0=\sqrt{\frac{\mu\ g (3mA+mB)}{R (mB-mA)}}$

Comment: thank you so much for such a comprehensive answer! However, I suppose, in your answer one point is missing - the block B experiences not only +T and +FrB, but also +FrA (according to the Newton's third law), doesn't it?

Comment: Then in the final expression there will be not (2mA+mB), but (3mA+mB), which is an essential difference...

Comment: You are absolutely correct about adding $FrA$ and I have edited my answer.  Solving the equations I get new results, but different from yours.

Comment: My mistake, I guess they are the same.